# Lessening The Impact of Applied Seasonal Factors on Data w/ a Growth Rate

Tags: regression, time-series, seasonality

I'm working on a forecasting project, where I'm trying to forecast out 12 months. I used a monthly seasonal dummy model to estimate seasonal factors. After attaining the seasonal factors I seasonally adjust the data and apply the monthly growth rate.

My problem is that when I apply the seasonal factors and the monthly growth rate the data significantly deviates from the yearly growth rate.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to handle this? Is there any literature on handling seasonal adjustments/ mitigating the impact of the seasonal adjustment so that my growth rate isn't completely thrown off?